# JSON object transformation

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have `JSON object` formatted as

```
{ 
   id: 'a60c09fa-9b60-4b14-9ee6-41d64d243435',
   contactData: {
      phone: '526 669 77',
      email: 'client@test.ee',
      skype: 'skype',
      company_name: 'CLIent22',
      address: 'address',
      contact_person: 'Person'
   }
}
```

I want to transform it into

```
{ 
       id: 'a60c09fa-9b60-4b14-9ee6-41d64d243435',
       phone: '526 669 77',
       email: 'client@test.ee',
       skype: 'skype',
       company_name: 'CLIent22',
       address: 'address',
       contact_person: 'Person'
    }
```

How it could be done. Looking for your help and advices.

Comment: is it fine, to mutate the original object?

Comment: That isn't valid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
var yourobject ={ 
   id: 'a60c09fa-9b60-4b14-9ee6-41d64d243435',
   contactData: {
      phone: '526 669 77',
      email: 'client@test.ee',
      skype: 'skype',
      company_name: 'CLIent22',
      address: 'address',
      contact_person: 'Person'
   }
}
var newObject=yourobject.contactData;
newObject.id=yourobject.id;
```

Comment: glad it help please don't forget to mark it as answered

Answer (score 3):

in ES6:

```
let result = {
  id: input.id,
  ...input.contactData
}
```

or using jQuery:

```
var result = $.extend({ id: input.id }, input.contactData);
```

Comment: I'm not using jQuery, and unfortunately I can't use ES6 syntax, but your answer looks good, but not in my case

Comment: Well I guess the answer of @jitender will do fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) for generating a copy of the object, without mutating the original object. Thenn add the additional properties.

```js
var original = { id: 'a60c09fa-9b60-4b14-9ee6-41d64d243435', contactData: { phone: '526 669 77', email: 'client@test.ee', skype: 'skype', company_name: 'CLIent22', address: 'address', contact_person: 'Person' } },
    result = Object.create(original.contactData);

result.id = original.id;
console.log(result);
console.log(original);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```